# How to make a jQuery table editable for specific column only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, jeditable

The code I have is below using a simple DataTable . I get the data and all sorting is great but now I want to update the cell contents in last column only which is the "reason not covered" column  and submit it back as update to DB possibly by AJAX calls  . I am not sure whether to use Editor or JEditable to make the table editable and how to make it editable for that column alone . Have tried different options using makeEditable and Editor but cannot make the inline cell contents editable for column or cell .Have **dataTables.editor.min.js** in the script path. Also tried jEditable with **jquery.jeditable.mini.js** Any help deeply appreciated.

**jquery-3.1.1.min.js, jquery.dataTables.min.js, dataTables.buttons.min.js, buttons.colVis.min.js, dataTables.editor.min.js**

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selectedDetails').DataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "fixedHeader": true,
            "scrollY": '400px'
        });


    } );</script>



    <table id = "selectedDetails" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
     <caption><h3>DETAILS FOR SELECTED FILTERS: <font color="brown">FORM ID</font>=<font color="blue"><%=request.getAttribute("formNameSelection")%></font> AND <font color="brown">COVERED IN AUTOTAX</font> = <font color="blue"><%=request.getAttribute("YesOrNoValueSelection") %></font> </h3></caption>         
       <thead style="background-color:#D7DBDD; border:solid 2px; border-color:black">           
        <tr>
            <th>FORM ID</th>
            <th>FIELD ID</th>
            <th>FIELD NAME</th>
            <th>FIELD TYPE</th>
            <th>NO: OF HARD CALCS</th>
            <th>NO: OF DROP ASSIGNEDS</th>
            <th>COVERED IN AUTOTAX ?</th>
            <th>REASON NOT COVERED</th>
        </tr>
        <thead>
       </thead>
        <tbody>            
        <c:forEach var="filterFieldInfo" items="${filteredValues}">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.formId}" /></td>
                <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.fieldId}" /></td>
                <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.fieldName}" /></td>
                <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.fieldType}" /></td>
                <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.numHardCalcs}" /></td>
                <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.numDroptAssigneds}" /></td>
                <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.autoTaxCovered}" /></td>
                <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.reasonAutoTaxCovered}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
       </tbody> 
    </table>
```

Comment: I have a button control fully editable table here http://jsbin.com/yafuvah/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I actually created a table that uses content editable on two fields on a table  that my users use. I will try to remember to post that code on Monday if that is still helpful for you

Comment: thank you @Bindrid , I tried your first solution but was not able to make it editable ..in fact none of the columns is editable , I am missing something obviously ..

Comment: it works on a row being selected then clicking the edit button. Last time I checked jsbin, it was working. In any case, my solution on my work computer is simpler.

Comment: ok, where or how do you make the row editable?

Comment: My company with not get a license for the table editor tool so none of my code samples include it

Answer (score 1):

I made one more.  This one, the html is created server side.
Also, it uses a pop over to allow the user to enter in the changes that way.

Like I said, I do not have access to the DataTable Editor library so I used the QTip2 (http://qtip2.com/) library instead.

Click on any cell in the office column.

http://jsbin.com/datecoy/edit?js,output

```
 // Table defintion
    $(document).ready(function () {


        var dtTable = $('#example').DataTable({
            columns: [{ title: "Name" }, { title: "Postition" }, { title: 'Office' }, { title: "Age" }, { title: "Start Date" }, { title: "Salary" }],
            columnDefs: [{ targets: [2], className: "editColumn" }]
        });

        $('#example').on("click", ".editColumn", function () {

           var index = $(this).index();
           var cols = dtTable.settings()[0].aoColumns;
           var colTitle = cols[index].title;
           var data = dtTable.rows($(this).closest("tr")).data()[0];

           DataTableDialog(this, colTitle, data[2]);

        })

    });
```

Comment: Thank you @Bindrid . I was able to make it work finally with this example ...I just need a way to persist this data to DB via a AJAX call or something the column that I am updating values .

Comment: I updated http://jsbin.com/datecoy/edit?js,output with one possible solution to AJAX.  It is commented out though since the call is completely bogus.  It just pops up an alert to let you know that the ajax has been sent.

Comment: I did updated AJAX calls and its working !!! thanks again for all the timely help ..One thing I noticed in the update column solution is if I updated a cell which was way down at the bottom after entering the value in the popup and clicking Ok the control is taken to top of the screen automatically . This is annoying in cases where you are updating multiple records . I will see if I can update that to leave the mouse control at that scroll location ..Thanks again !!

Comment: What I did in a similar situation is made it so that if the user hits the tab key on the text box, it will automatically update that cell then move to the next one down and put it in edit mode.

Comment: nice idea will try it out today ...!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple one but not my first choice.  Because it is content editable, you loose control of the width of the column and end up with some strange looking stuff.

Just click on a cell in the edit column and start typing.

event handlers keep the data object and the table cell in sync.

http://jsbin.com/zizepoh/edit?html,js,output

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add editable column data
    var dtData =  $.map(dataStore.data, function(item){item.contentEdit = "";  return item;});

    var dtTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": dtData,
        "select":"single",
        "columnDefs":[{"targets":[6], render : function(ditem){return "<div contenteditable>" + ditem + "</div>";}}],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }, 
            {"data":"contentEdit", "className": "contentEdit"}

        ], 
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [ 'excelHtml5' ]
     });

   // Uses key press event handler to keep the associated data object in sync
   $("#example").on("keypress", ".contentEdit div", function (){
       var rData = dtTable.rows($(this).closest("tr")).data()[0];
       rData.contentEdit = $(this).text();
       $("#txtFollower").val($(this).text());
   });
});
```

Comment: than you ! ..Seems like this is exactly what i need , will try it and let you know ..Hope this can be done on the last column which gas data for eg Salary right and also we can persist the data back to database using ajax calls without much trouble ..haven't reached till there ..Appreciate your assistance a lot again . My problem is the table never becomes editable for me for my code example ...maybe I am missing a js library thats needed ..?

Comment: Most the stuff is done with jquery so if your table is working at all, I doubt you are missing js library.

Comment: Is there any way to increase the size of the tool tip ...I changed the style but increases the whole size of the tool tip not the buttons and the text box

Comment: I actually use a  plugin for my tooltips so I can completely customize them.  http://qtip2.com/

Answer (score 0):

this one is a tad safer and more obvious. it puts in a textbox.

Also, I had to add a bit more to make the excel dump work.

http://jsbin.com/zufesop/3/edit?html,js,output

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add editable column data
    var dtData =  $.map(dataStore.data, function(item){item.contentEdit = "";  return item;});

    var dtTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": dtData,
        "select":"single",
        "columnDefs":[{"targets":[6], render : function(ditem){return "<input type='text' value = '" + ditem +"'/>" ;}}],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }, 
            {"data":"contentEdit", "className": ""}

        ], 
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text: 'Save as Excel',
                // updates the data before being sent to excel
                customizeData: function (a, b, c, d) {
                    var exd = a.body;
                    var dtdata = $('#example').DataTable().rows().data();
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < dtdata.length ; ++ii) {
                        var cur = dtdata[ii].contentEdit;
                        exd[ii][6] = cur;
                    }
                }
            }
         ]
     });

   // Uses key press event handler to keep the associated data object in sync
   $("#example").on("keyup", "input[type='text']", function (){
       var rData = dtTable.rows($(this).closest("tr")).data()[0];
       rData.contentEdit = $(this).val();
       $("#txtFollower").val($(this).val());

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something for you to look at.

All of my tables are made from an array data objects in JavaScript. Yours, I think, was made from an html table generated server side.

So, to closer emulate what you are doing I created a table server side and then tried to use my code to update it. It did not work.  Below is what I had to do update it.

Basically, the code below uses an event handler that pops up an input box for the user to make the change and then save it.  (I left all of that out)

```
                    // For my object array, this was all I had to do to update the data.
                    var dtTable = $($(target).closest("table")).DataTable();
                    var dtData = dtTable.rows($(target).closest("tr")).data()[0];
                    dtData.office = $(this).siblings("input").val();
                    dtTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
```

When I changed it to a server side table, the code above stopped working (even after changing it to work with array of arrays which server side tables use)

To get it to work, I had to update both the data object and the tables html node so it looked like this:

```
                    var columnIndex = $(target).index();
                    var dtTable = $($(target).closest("table")).DataTable();
                    var dtData = dtTable.rows($(target).closest("tr")).data()[0];
                    // here, I updated the data node
                    dtData[columnIndex] = $(this).siblings("input").val();
                    // then I updated the html td. Once that was done, it started working for the server side table.
                    $(target).html(dtData[columnIndex]);
                    dtTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

THanks a bunch again ! I have modified code with your example to try make it work to see what I am missing , below is the modified script and html . In your example I just needed the Edit and Save button , no functionality needed for Add and  Delete. Below still doesn't work , I dont actually see even an edit button .   What are the parameters inside the function function (e, dt, bt, config) signify ?

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

            var myTable = $('#selectedDetails').DataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "fixedHeader": true,
                "scrollY": '400px',
                buttons: [{
                    text: "Edit", className :"editButton",
                      extend: "selectedSingle",
                      action: function (e, dt, bt, config) { editRow(e, dt, bt, config); }
                  }, {
                      text: "Save",
                      extend: "selectedSingle",
                      action: function (e, dt, bt, config) { saveRow(e, dt, bt, config); }
                  }
                  }],
                  dom: "Btp",
                  select: "single"
            });

            var dataObject = myTable.rows().data();

            // keep the rows from deselection when you click on a textbox
            // this means you have to click between textboxes to change edit rows when more than one is open

            $("#selectedDetails").on("click", "input", function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); return false; });

            table.on('user-select', function (e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent) {
                if ($('#selectedDetails input').length > 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }); 

        });


            // Save the selected row (assuming its in edit mode)
            function saveRow(e, dt, bt, config) {
                var r = dt.rows(".selected").nodes()[0];

                // if row is not edit mode, just return.
                if ($("input", r).length === 0) { return; }


                var d = dt.rows(".selected").data()[0];
                var containsText = false;
                $(r).children("td").each(function (i, it) {
                    var di = $("input", it).val();
                    if (di.length > 0) { containsText = true; }
                    $(it).html(di);
                    d[i] = di;
                });
                if (!containsText) {
                    alert("This row contains no data and will be removed");
                    dt.rows(".selected").remove().draw();
                }
              $(".editButton span").text("Edit");
            }

            // Puts a row in edit mode
            function editRow(e, dt, bt, config) {
               var r = dt.rows(".selected").nodes()[0];
             if(  $("span", bt[0]).text() == "Cancel"){

               if($(r).hasClass("newRow")){
                  dt.rows(".selected").remove().draw();
               }
               else {
               $(r).children("td").each(function (i, it) {
                    var od = dt.cells(it).data();
                    $(it).html(od[0]);
                });
               } 

               $("span", bt[0]).text("Edit");
               return;
             }

                // if row already in edit mode, just return.
                if ($("input", r).length > 0) { return; }

                $(r).children("td").each(function (i, it) {
                    var h = $("<input type='text'>");
                    h.val(it.innerText);
                    $(it).html(h);
                });
              $("span", bt[0]).text("Cancel");
            }   



            </script>

        <table id = "selectedDetails" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
         <caption><h3>DETAILS FOR SELECTED FILTERS: <font color="brown">FORM ID</font>=<font color="blue"><%=request.getAttribute("formNameSelection")%></font> AND <font color="brown">COVERED IN AUTOTAX</font> = <font color="blue"><%=request.getAttribute("YesOrNoValueSelection") %></font> </h3></caption>         
           <thead style="background-color:#D7DBDD; border:solid 2px; border-color:black">           
            <tr>
                <th>FORM ID</th>
                <th>FIELD ID</th>
                <th>FIELD NAME</th>
                <th>FIELD TYPE</th>
                <th>NO: OF HARD CALCS</th>
                <th>NO: OF DROP ASSIGNEDS</th>
                <th>COVERED IN AUTOTAX ?</th>
                <th>REASON NOT COVERED</th>
            </tr>
            <thead>
           </thead>
            <tbody>            
            <c:forEach var="filterFieldInfo" items="${filteredValues}">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.formId}" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.fieldId}" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.fieldName}" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.fieldType}" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.numHardCalcs}" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.numDroptAssigneds}" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.autoTaxCovered}" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 45px;text-align: center;" align="center"><c:out value="${filterFieldInfo.reasonAutoTaxCovered}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
           </tbody> 
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[contentEditable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) anyone?

Says it's new for HTML5, and also a "Global HTML" attribute.

Seems to work pretty well on table cells.